# Need to get values from two columns of different rows in a single row

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table data like below

[image: table]

My requirement is to have the Arrival and Departure at the same row with the latest EventTime for each route like below.

[image: target]

Can someone help me on this. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: you should add your attempt at the SQL

Answer (score 0):

Basic `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    Route,
    Date,
    MAX(Arrival) AS Arrival,
    MAX(Departure) AS Departure,
    MAX(EventDate) AS EventDate
FROM
    TableName
GROUP BY
    Route,
    Date
ORDER BY
    Route,
    Date
;
```

Comment: Actually this is not working as expected, Arrival and Departure is still coming in different rows

Comment: This 100% should work. Grouping by Route and Date results in a single row for each RouteDate combo. Make sure your Date column is an actual Date and not a DateTime or something. Beyond that, please put forth a bit of effort to figure it out.